# VBS-file to hide a java program use much cpu-time?

Tags: vbscript, cmd

The Jar-file itself I use, doesn't consume much cpu-time.
However when I start the jar-file thru a .vbs-file it consumes much more until the limit of cpu.

Could be something changed in the vbs-file, I don't know well the programing language Visual Basic ?

Thanks

```
Dim oShell
bVisible = 0
' one line of code follows
sCmd = """C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe"" -Xms128m    -Xmx512m -jar ""C:\someJar.jar"""
' end of single line of code
bWaitOnReturn = True
Set oShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run sCmd, bVisible, bWaitOnReturn
```

Comment: Why do you start it through vbs?

Comment: I tried to hide the console window from the jar-file in windows7. It's for testing.

Comment: How did you get such a bad idea? Make it a runnable jar and make sure it's run with `javaw.exe` and not `java.exe`. Running a java program through VBS...jeez.

Comment: I tried to start the jar-file with javaw instead of java, but seems to open only a console window without doing something.

Comment: @Kayaman
javaw -jar C:\someJar.jar ?

Comment: Run it in the console window to see if any errors are occurring.

Comment: It showed me a pop-up window (Java Virtual machine Launcher) with an error "unable to access jarfile someJar jar" ?

Comment: Now it's time for you to stop asking questions and start solving the real problem.

Comment: Strange javaw.exe consumed also much cpu-time, now I closed the Process. But the Jar-file didn't execute.

Comment: Okay the error showed before was just because the console was not in Administrator. The javaw comand didn't show any errors.

Comment: Which real problem. I tried to start the .bat-file as administrator with javaw, but it doesn't work. Thanks (> perhaps to chat?)

Comment: No thanks. I'm not very familiar with Windows' problems with running java programs. I just remember that `javaw` is the executable that doesn't open a console window. I'd imagine there's something wrong with your settings if you need to be an administrator to run Java.

Comment: I think it was because the .bat file resides in the administrator area, but I tried it also without admin. Perhaps someone knows nonetheless about vbs-code ? I found the visual basic script thru the web.

Comment: This is an XY problem. *I can't figure out how to properly do X, so I'm trying to work around that issue by doing this other thing Y, but doing Y is causing me lots of problems. How can I do Y?*. Instead, you should be trying to do  properly, in which case all the problems you've caused with Y will disappear. Solve the problem you're actually having, instead of trying to kludge your way around it by adding VBS into the mix when it's totally unnecessary.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thank you, I found how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the Console "start" should be added.

> start javaw -jar someJar.jar

The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there is no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want a command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some reason.

from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Perhaps to hide a Java-Gui a vbs could be helpful.